# Parser accepting corrupt input

Tags: xtext

I have a simple grammar like this:

```
grammar RuleDSL with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate ruledsl "http://www.ruledsl.org"

Model:
    rules += Rule*;
    
Rule:
    rule = 'Rule' '{' subrules += Subrule*  '}'
;   

Subrule: fieldA=ID opName=Operator fieldC=INT ';';
Operator:
    '<' | '<=' | '=' | '>=' | '>' 
;
```

And I wonder why this input is accepted:

> ```
>   Rule {
>           field1 > 5
>           field3 = a          
>   }
> ```

This is parsed by

```
@RunWith(XtextRunner)
@InjectWith(RuledslInjectorProvider)
class RuledslParsingTest{

    @Inject
    ParseHelper<Model> parseHelper

    @Test 
    def void loadModel() {          
        val result = parseHelper.parse('''
            Rule {
                field1 > 5
                field3 = a
            }
        ''')
        println(result)
     }
}
```

and yields - after some iterating through the tree and printing the `Subrule` -:

> field1>5
>
> field3=0
>
> anull0

I can't figure out why this happens. In the generated Eclipse PlugIn, this input is labeled incorrect as it should be.

Comment: Did you ask the Results eresource for errors? You may have a look at validationtesthelper as well

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Maybe you could add something like `assertEquals(0, result.eResource.errors.size)` to the generated `Hello World` testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an ask the `result` for its `eResource` and the Resource for its errors. you may have a look at ValidationTestHelper as well.